# How to convert Excel text to date and time

Tags: excel, vba

One of my Excel column contains data like this:  `2/15/2011 2:00:00 AM`. I need to convert it to two columns: date and time. I tried `Cdate`, `DateValue`, left functions it all give type mismatch error. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

To convert one DateTime string into 2 separate strings:

```
Public Sub splitDateTime()

    Dim d As String, t As String

    d = DateValue("2/15/2011 2:00:00 AM")
    t = TimeValue("2/15/2011 2:00:00 AM")

    MsgBox d    '"2/15/2011"  (result format varies based on Regional Settings)
    MsgBox t    '"2:00:00 AM"

End Sub
```

To convert all cells in a column containing DataTime strings into 2 columns, except for Headers:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub splitDateTime()
    Dim str As String, cel As Range, ws As Worksheet, lr As Long

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    lr = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each cel In ws.Range("C1:C" & lr)
        If cel.Row = 1 Then
            With cel
                .Value2 = "Date"
                .Offset(0, 1).Value2 = "Time"
            End With
        Else
            str = cel.Value2
            With cel
                .Value2 = Format(DateValue(str), "ddd, mmm dd yyyy")
                .Offset(0, 1).Value2 = Format(TimeValue(str), "hh:mm:ss AmPm")
            End With
        End If
    Next
    ws.Range("C1:D" & lr).EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Here is my code and it still gives the type mismatch error.

Comment: Option Explicit

Sub splitDateTime()

    Dim cvalue
    Dim curr_date As String
      
    Columns("C").Select
    cvalue = Columns("C").Value
    curr_date = DateValue(cvalue)
    
    MsgBox curr_date

End Sub

Comment: The code provided is to show you an example of how to do it. Please edit your question to be more specific, like "I need to split all cells in column C from full Date and Time format into the date value, to remain in each cell in column C and time value into a corresponding cell in column D"

Comment: I did test your code and it works perfectly. In my case, however, column C hosts datetime data like  2/14/2011 2:00:00 AM.

Comment: I edited the answer to split col C into col C and D. Please adjust the code to fit your specific requirement since you didn't mention what the 2nd column should be

Comment: Thanks Paul. I realized that I included the column header in the code that made type mismatch. Your original code snippet is very helpful. Now I face another challenge: after I get date and time I want to insert to two new columns and name them Date and time respectively. I know the way to do for a single cell but do not know how to deal with a column. Please give some hints. Thanks.

Comment: See my edits. Please close the question if the answer addresses the initial issues. If you need more help open new questions and make them as complete and specific as you can, related to the end result (what you want to accomplish)

Comment: I tested it and it works perfectly. Instead of creating Columns Date and Time at the same worksheet, I wonder how to do it to a separate worksheet. This is the very first Excel macro project I ever worked. Your help is so much valuable to me. My sincere appreciation to you.

Comment: great ! for your next change try to figure it out on your own and if you'll find it too challenging post it as a new question with the specific code you tried to solve the problem, small sample of current data structure (2 columns on the same sheet) and the end result (column 1 on the initial sheet, and column 2 on the specific sheet you want)

Comment: Thanks so much, Paul. I figured out the way to copy the values to a separate sheet.